# When adding command: in my deployment.yaml my pod goes CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When I add any command into deployment.yaml, my pod goes CrashLoopBackOff, if I remove the commands it works fine. 
The kubectl logs show me "Hello" but the http seems dont start.

```js
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        env:
    {{- range $pkey, $pval := .Values.env }}
        - name: {{ $pkey }}
          value: {{ quote $pval }}
{{- end }}
        **command: ["echo hello"]**
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationGracePeriodSeconds }}
{{- end }}
```

can anyone help me??
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Docker container gets killed once the process running inside it is exited. In your case the Pod starts a container but then there is nothing to do after echo hello, thus container gets terminated with success code. But kubernetes will by default try to bring it up again, thus it spawns another container but that exits again, and this happens in a loop, thus you get CrashLoopBackOff

Comment: Thank you for the response! 
Do you know how do I stop this loop, so my command runs and the conteiners inside the pod are healthy?
Thanks!

Comment: Delete the problematic `command:` line, and run `helm update` to update the installed deployment spec.  This will delete the failing pods and create new ones.